# IntelliJ does not compile source files, unless I put "Build Project" in Before Launch steps

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, kotlin-java-interop

I have a maven project for Cucumber in Java, where I am mixing Java+Kotlin. The maven build works fine and compiles files as I change them. But when I run a test (*.feature file) from IntelliJ, the files are not compiled.

As per the default *'Run Configuration'*, the step to run *'Before Launch'* of test is **'Build'**. If I change the configuration to run **'Build Project'** instead, the files are getting compiled. But it should work even with default **'Build'** step. It won't be feasible to ask the whole team to change their default settings only to use Kotlin in a working Java project.

I am using Kotlin v1.7.21. I tried deleting all the *.idea/.., *.iml* files and reimporting the project multiple times without any luck.

[Github project to reproduce](https://github.com/vikrant21st/cucumberkotlin)

[image: Kotlin compiler settings]

I have tried below Q&A, but none of them worked 
[Changing the order of maven plugins execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243912/changing-the-order-of-maven-plugins-execution)
[Intellij Idea won't compile kotlin but maven does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44063633/intellij-idea-wont-compile-kotlin-but-maven-does)

Comment: Can you attach a link to your project?

Comment: Attached @vanyochek. Do you see what could be the issue?

Comment: This feature isn't implemented yet — see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-12004/Please-make-it-possible-to-run-Cucumber-scenario-from-.feature-in-kotlin-project.

Comment: It seems like a **bug** rather than a missing feature. The sources under *test/* path are not "built" by IntelliJ *Build* when we add Kotlin support, but *main/* sources are built. Cucumber test is run as if it is not a test. *Cucumber for Java* (or maybe *Kotlin IDE*) plugin needs to be "adjusted" to fix it

Comment: @vikrant21st I have exact the same experience with a project that was refactored into a monorepo. So basically the entire project moved into a subfolder. Since that change, we need to use "Build project" in the Cucumber run configuration. Otherwise it would not pickup changed `.json` files.